# Force.com IDE - Use Stored Passwords to Deploy to Server - Now that it's Open Source, we could do it

Tags: force.com, deployment, ide, eclipse

I was very happy to read this great article by @PeterKnolle about the Force.com IDE is now Open Source and the ability to let us extend and improve this tool:

http://peterknolle.com/extending-the-force-com-ide/

One of my personal top issues in force.com IDE is the need to manually re-enter password and token everytime when we deploy to a server, even if we have the target-org already saved as project containing username and password. Since the credentials are already stored in eclipse, I can't see any additional security issues.

I know that mavensmate can do this already. Even deploy to multiple targets. But for different reasons we tend to use force.com IDE form time to time.

Easiest thing would be just to have an additional Picklist containing all existing projects at the top of "Deploy to server..." modal dialog, just above "Organization Settings". After selecting anything, the "Organization Settings" could populate. Also nice would be to have the last destination as default pre-populated.

Sounds not too hard, but I never touched eclipse extension development in my life.

So I'm wondering if I'm the only one who is missing this and if maybe someone else has already thought about writing this enhancement?

Comment: This would be better placed on the Force.com IDE Github page (https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore), most likely as an issue.

Comment: Yes, thanks @AlexTennant, I will add it also there. I just wanted to ask here too before I possibly look into it deeper or try to fix it myself....

Comment: As this isn't really a discussion forum, it's probably best placed on http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/ if you want to float the idea with the SFSE community

Comment: @AlexTennant agreed. Any way to move it there - or delete/recreate?

Comment: I'm sure a moderator could do it auto-magically. I think for us mere mortals the only option is delete/recreate.